Wrap Powershell in Progress class
I'm trying to implement a class wrapper around Powershell.
It almost works, except that it hangs when it cannot read any more output from the STREAM.
So it manages to read all output, but after theres no more, it just hangs in IMPORT statement:
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

    CLASS Powershell:

    DEF PRIVATE STREAM stPowershell.
    
    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC Powershell():
        INPUT-OUTPUT STREAM stPowershell THROUGH VALUE("powershell").
        THIS-OBJECT:ReadOutput().
    END.
    
    DESTRUCTOR Powershell():
        INPUT-OUTPUT STREAM stPowershell CLOSE.
    END.
    
    METHOD PUBLIC CHAR Input(i_cInput AS CHAR):
        IF i_cInput = ? THEN UNDO, THROW NEW Progress.Lang.AppError(SUBST("&1: 'i_cInput' is 'UNKNOWN'!", PROGRAM-NAME(1))).
        
        PUT STREAM stPowershell UNFORMATTED i_cInput SKIP.
        
        RETURN THIS-OBJECT:ReadOutput().
    END.
    
    METHOD PROTECTED CHAR ReadOutput():
    
        DEF VAR cOutputs AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
        DEF VAR cOutput  AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
        DEF VAR lFirst   AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO INIT TRUE.
        
        REPEAT:
            IF lFirst THEN lFirst = FALSE.
                      ELSE cOutputs = cOutputs + "~n".
            
            IMPORT STREAM stPowershell UNFORMATTED cOutput NO-ERROR.
            cOutputs = cOutputs + cOutput.
        END.
        
        RETURN cOutputs.
    END.
    
END.

Usage:
DEF VAR oPowershell AS CLASS Powershell NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR cOutput     AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

oPowershell = NEW Powershell().
cOutput = oPowershell:Input("$num = 12").
cOutput = oPowershell:Input("(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).Popup($num, 0, 'Done', 0x0)").
cOutput = oPowershell:Input("Write-Output 'test output'").


I'm not super familiar with ABL/OpenEdge, but try testing whether the stream has anything to read with IF SEEK(stPowerShell) <> ? THEN [... proceed to read output] or similar

@MathiasR.Jessen Progress documentarion states that  ’SEEK’ statement doesn’t work in this case: https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/SEEK-statement.html

How is the output terminated? Is there a final newline? Or does it just close the output?

@TomBascom According to READKEY Powershell terminates each output line to ~r~r. If read with IMPORT, it adds ~n in the end of each read line

Is your goal to have a "pipe" open between OpenEdge and a Powershell instance so that you can send arbitrary commands back and forth and scrape their output? Or is your goal to run specific commands from time to time? (Like your "ping" example.) I am struggling to understand why you aren't just using OS-COMMAND or a more direct invocation of INPUT THROUGH.

I think the pipe fits my goal. The idea is to wrap the Powershell session in object instance, and use that instance to communicate between the OpenEdge and Powershell. Since the session stays the same, we have more possibilities. For example, we could use this for SFTP or SSH.

I managed to get this version to work, but I wouldn't call it a perfect solution.
To avoid the output read hanging issue, I made the Powershell output EOF character after each command. This way all synchronous execution will always end in EOF character in the Powershell output. We will read the output until we reach the EOF and stop there.
Possible problems can arise if we're running asynchronous commands, or the output contains EOF characters.
I think the best solution would require us to use platform specific APIs (for example WIN32 API). We need a way to read all existing output. But I think this version will work for a lot of normal cases.
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

CLASS Powershell:
    
    &SCOPED-DEFINE POWERSHELL_EOF "[char]26"
    &SCOPED-DEFINE PROGRESS_EOF   26
    
    DEF PRIVATE STREAM stPowershell.
    
    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC Powershell():
        
        /* Start new 'Powershell' */
        INPUT-OUTPUT STREAM stPowershell THROUGH VALUE("powershell") NO-ECHO.
        
        /* Disable prompt */
        PUT STREAM stPowershell UNFORMATTED "$global:Prompt = $null" SKIP.
        
        /* Flush startup output */
        THIS-OBJECT:Read().
    END.
    
    DESTRUCTOR Powershell():
        INPUT-OUTPUT STREAM stPowershell CLOSE.
    END.
    
    METHOD PUBLIC CHAR Write(i_cInput AS CHAR):
        IF i_cInput = ? THEN UNDO, THROW NEW Progress.Lang.AppError(SUBST("&1: 'i_cInput' is 'UNKNOWN'!", PROGRAM-NAME(1))).
        
        /* Write input */
        PUT STREAM stPowershell UNFORMATTED i_cInput SKIP.
        
        /* Read output */
        RETURN THIS-OBJECT:Read().
    END.
    
    METHOD PROTECTED CHAR Read():
        
        DEF VAR cOutputs AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
        
        /* Output 'EOF' manually */
        PUT STREAM stPowershell UNFORMATTED {&POWERSHELL_EOF} SKIP.
        
        /* Read all output until 'EOF' */
        REPEAT:
            READKEY STREAM stPowershell PAUSE 0.
            
            /* If we reached the 'EOF', stop reading */
            IF LASTKEY = {&PROGRESS_EOF} THEN DO:
                LEAVE.
            END.
            
            cOutputs = cOutputs + CHR(LASTKEY).
        END.
        
        RETURN cOutputs.
    END.
    
END.


You might try something like this:
METHOD PROTECTED CHAR ReadOutput():
    
    DEF VAR cOutputs AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

    do while true:

        readkey STREAM stPowershell pause 0.

        if lastkey <= 0 then
          leave.
         else
          cOutputs = cOutputs + chr( lastkey ).

    END.
    
    RETURN cOutputs.

END.


Thanks Tom, but this seems to have the exact same issue. It reads all output correctly but after the last existing character the  READKEY hangs code doesn't continue anymore..

It seems like this version gets more output read. The IMPORT seems to hang when the last row is missing "~n" in the end. This one goes till the very end but also hangs after last character.

READKEY should be returning -1 when it times out because there is no more input. That should cause the LEAVE to execute. If that happens the "RETURN cOutputs." should be executing (add a MESSAGE just prior to it to verify). If that is all true then the "hang" isn't in READKEY or ReadOutput(), it is in some other part of your code. If I had to guess I would guess that your Powershell is waiting for some input and has not terminated so the output stream is still open.

I did some more testing. It seems that if I use a direct command (for example ping google.com in the INPUT-OUTPUT THROUGH instead of powershell, the output can be read normally without hanging.
It seems like the output reading expects that the stream is already 'closed' when we read it. Meaning when we run a single command, it is run, it outputs its stuff to output stream, and exits. After this output reading is successful.
However, if we keep the stream open after this and try to run a second command with PUT, the commands do nothing and output is always empty

One way to make this to work is to know how many lines there exists in the output after each sent command. We could run additional EOF output after the actual command, and use the READKEY to read until it counter this EOF and stops reading until we send a new command..

No, IMPORT and READKEY don’t assume the ‘output’ is closed. They will happily read data as long as it is available. I notice that you have not confirmed (or denied) if READKEY PAUSE 0. Returned a -1. The difference between a “direct command” and a shell is that a shell is expecting more commands so, by design, it is not closing its  output after each command. (Although many shells also often have options to run a single command and then terminate, maybe that is what you need here?)

READKEY PAUSE 0 does not return anything after the last output character, since it hangs on that statement eternally. So we never manage to get -1 since the code hangs on that last READKEY PAUSE 0 statement and we never get to read LASTKEY.
For example if output has ab, it manages to read a and b, but after b it tries to get one more character and in that situation READKEY PAUSE 0 hangs and code running stops there eternally. Only stopping the process will help after that.
READKEY and IMPORT just doesn't seem to work with powershell or cmd when reading output

Ok, the failure of READKEY to return confirms (to me) that the problem is that powershell.exe isn't closing its output when it is done. (Maybe that's obvious to you but it wasn't to me.) So my solution of using READKEY isn't going to work all by itself. But it was at least helpful, from my POV, to debug the problem.
